# Error generando options dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

Tengo una tabla dinámica donde tengo un select que se debe de cargar con la cantidad de option dependiendo el numero que coloque en un input es decir que si pongo en el input 4 se debe generar 4 opciones en mi select, ok eso lo tengo pero solo me funciona en el primer row puesto es una tabla dinámica en el siguiente row que se genera no toma los valores de los opciones que debería de generarse.

Esta es mi vista para que se hagan la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es el problema que me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion de mi tabla y del select

```
<script>
var addButton = $('.addRow');
var wrapper = $('.tabla_autores');

$(addButton).click(function (e) {

    var x = $("#cantidadAutoresReales").val();
    var count = parseInt(x) + parseInt(1);
   
    var tr = `<tr id='row[]'>
              <td>
                <input type='hidden' name='from_user_id[]' id='from_user_id[]' value='{{auth()->user()->id}}'>
                <input type='hidden' value='{{\Carbon\Carbon::now();}}' name='hora_inicio[]' id='hora_inicio'>
                <select class='form-control 'name='software_version[]' id='software_version[]' >
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach($software as $sf)
                  <option value='{{$sf->id}}'>{{$sf->name_software}} - {{$sf->name_version}}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class='form-control' name='producto[]' id='producto[]'>
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach($productos as $items)
                  <option value='{{$items->id_producto}}'>{{$items->descripcion}}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class=form-control name='instalador_asignado[]' id='instalador_asignado[]'>
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach ($empleados as $emp)
                  <option value='{{ $emp->id }}'>{{ $emp->username }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
                <td>
                <select name='pc_asignada[]' id='pcs'>
                <option value='pc_1'>PC 1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class='form-control' name='medio_instalacion[]' id='id_medio_instalacion' value='' >
                    <option disabled value='' selected>Seleccionar...</option>
                    @foreach ($medio_instalacion as $emp)
                    <option value='{{ $emp->id_medio_instalacion }}'>{{ $emp->descripcion }}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td><input name='id_medio[]'  class='form-control' type='text' autocomplete='off' required></td>
              <td><input name='contraseña_medio[]' class='form-control' type='text' autocomplete='off' required></td>
             <th><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-danger deleteRow'>x</a></th>
            </tr>`;
           $('tbody').append(tr);
});

$('tbody').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});


jQuery("#miinput").on("change", function() {
var cantidad = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
jQuery("#pcs").empty();
for (i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
    jQuery("#pcs").append('<option value="pc_' + i + '">PC ' + i + '</option>"');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Lo primero es que no debes repetir ID's. Cuando agregas una fila dinámicamente con los id fijos en la plantillas los estas repitiendo. A lo menos debes cambiar el select de los pc

de

```
<select name='pc_asignada[]' id='pcs'>
```

Por una clase

```
<select name="pc_asignada[]" class="pcs">
```

2.- Yo crearía una función que me retornara un string con los options, de esta manera

```
function GetOptions(cantidad)
{
   let opts="";
   for (i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
     opts += '<option value="pc_' + i + '">PC ' + i + '</option>';
   }
   return opts;
}
```

3.- Luego en tu función agregar fila, aquí veremos cuantos "PC" deben agregarse al options y los agregamos

```
$(addButton).click(function (e) {

    var x = $("#cantidadAutoresReales").val();
    var count = parseInt(x) + parseInt(1);
   
    let cantidad_pcs =  Number(jQuery("#miinput").val()); //Aquí obtenemos la cantidad

    var tr = `<tr id='row[]'>
              <td>
                <input type='hidden' name='from_user_id[]' id='from_user_id[]' value='{{auth()->user()->id}}'>
                <input type='hidden' value='{{\Carbon\Carbon::now();}}' name='hora_inicio[]' id='hora_inicio'>
                <select class='form-control 'name='software_version[]' id='software_version[]' >
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach($software as $sf)
                  <option value='{{$sf->id}}'>{{$sf->name_software}} - {{$sf->name_version}}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class='form-control' name='producto[]' id='producto[]'>
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach($productos as $items)
                  <option value='{{$items->id_producto}}'>{{$items->descripcion}}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class=form-control name='instalador_asignado[]' id='instalador_asignado[]'>
                  <option disabled value='' selected>== Seleccione ==</option>
                  @foreach ($empleados as $emp)
                  <option value='{{ $emp->id }}'>{{ $emp->username }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </td>
                <td>
                <select name='pc_asignada[]' class='pcs'>
                ${GetOptions(cantidad_pcs);}
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class='form-control' name='medio_instalacion[]' id='id_medio_instalacion' value='' >
                    <option disabled value='' selected>Seleccionar...</option>
                    @foreach ($medio_instalacion as $emp)
                    <option value='{{ $emp->id_medio_instalacion }}'>{{ $emp->descripcion }}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td><input name='id_medio[]'  class='form-control' type='text' autocomplete='off' required></td>
              <td><input name='contraseña_medio[]' class='form-control' type='text' autocomplete='off' required></td>
             <th><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-danger deleteRow'>x</a></th>
            </tr>`;
           $('tbody').append(tr);
});
```

4.- En tu evento change, cuando cambia el input, ahora cambiamos todos los select's que puedan haber

```
jQuery("#miinput").on("change", function() {
   var cantidad = Number(jQuery(this).val());

   jQuery(".pcs").each(function(){
      jQuery(this).empty();
      jQuery(this).append( GetOptions(cantidad));
   });
});
```

5.- Como recomendación final: Ocupar Number en el lugar de parseInt

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me sirvio de mucho